# A value in this formula is of the wrong data type

Tags: excel

I cannot figure out why this formula is returning this error `A value used in this formula is of the wrong data type`

```
=IFNA(IF(OR(A2="DL", A2="DU", A2="EL", A2="EU", A2="F"), "N/A", IF(INDEX(Sheet1!$A2:$C705, MATCH(1, (B2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$705) * (C2=Sheet2!$B$2:$B$705) * (Sheet3!$B$26=Sheet2!$C$2:$C$705), 0), 3),"Y", "N")), "N/A")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the INDEX returning?

Comment: I can enter the formula without error, how are you entering it? Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Thank you Scott. Your comment prompted me to check what it was returning and it was returning a text value. For some reason I had it in my head that if I combined the index/match with the IF statement that it would just return true if there was a value and false if there wasn't a value.